# Possibility to stop low level access of RAM

Tags: windows-7, memory, blocking

Is it possible to stop specific programs from having access to low level RAM access of other programs.

For example if you install Cheat Engine it allows you to scan and edit memory address of another program would it be possible to stop it from accessing RAM that it shouldn't.

I know the simple answer is "don't use the program." but not the answer I am looking for and I have only used Cheat Engine as an example due to it being a program specifically for editing and scanning programs.

OS : Windows 7 SP1 Home Edition

Comment: What OS do you use? The answer highly depends on the OS used.

Comment: Sorry I should have put that in @UwePlonus I Edited OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run the program as a different user that should work (as long as the different user is a standard or low privileged user).

For more information have a look at:
[Process Security and Access Rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684880%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The specific privilege required is PROCESS_VM_READ which will normally only be granted to processes for the same user.